# Я написал телеграм бота, кнопки работают, а вот кнопка "Назад" не работает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def inline(massege):
  mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  catalog = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Каталог", callback_data="Catalog")
  help = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Поддержка", callback_data="help")
  mainmenu.add(catalog, help,)
  bot.send_message(massege.chat.id, "ВЫБЕРИТЕ КНОПКУ", reply_markup=mainmenu)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda a:True)
def inline(a):
  if a.data == 'Catalog':
    bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 1')
  elif a.data == 'help':
      menuhelp = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
      helper = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Связь с нами", callback_data="helper")
      backinmainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад", callback_data="backinmainmenu")
      menuhelp.add(helper, backinmainmenu)
      bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, 'Выбирите действие1', reply_markup=menuhelp)
      @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda b: True)
      def inline(b):
           if b.data == 'helper':
            bot.send_message(b.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 2')
           elif b.data == 'backinmainmenu':
               @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
               def inline(massege):
                   mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                   catalog = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Каталог", callback_data="Catalog")
                   help = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Поддержка", callback_data="help")
                   mainmenu.add(catalog, help,)
                   bot.send_message(massege.chat.id, "ВЫБЕРИТЕ КНОПКУ", reply_markup=mainmenu)


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересно, а если Вам придется возвращаться в коде к декоратору `@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])` с функцией  `inline` n-ое количество раз, вы будете ее тоже переписывать n-ое количество раз? Никогда не переписывайте код еще раз если в этом нет необходимости, и ознакомьтесь с правилом `DRY`.

Для вашего случая достаточно и одного обработчика для `inline-клавиатуры`.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def inline(massege):
  mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  catalog = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Каталог", callback_data="Catalog")
  help = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Поддержка", callback_data="help")
  mainmenu.add(catalog, help,)
  bot.send_message(massege.chat.id, "ВЫБЕРИТЕ КНОПКУ", reply_markup=mainmenu)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda a:True)
def inline_a(a):
    if a.data == 'Catalog':
        bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 1')
    elif a.data == 'help':
        menuhelp = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        helper = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Связь с нами", callback_data="helper")
        backinmainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад", callback_data="backinmainmenu")
        menuhelp.add(helper, backinmainmenu)
        bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, 'Выбирите действие', reply_markup=menuhelp)
    elif a.data == "helper":
        bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, 'Это кнопка 2')
    elif a.data == 'backinmainmenu':
        return inline(a.message)     

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо